# Calculate candidate keys given functional dependencies

Tags: database, database-design, functional-dependencies

I have a relation with the following functional dependencies :

```
A  -> B
AC -> D
EF -> AG
AG -> H

the couple (EG) is unique.
```

I want to calculate the candidate keys, should i add a functional dependency from the unique couple ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should absolutely add the FD `EG->ABCDFH`. If you don't you'll never determine that EG is a candidate key.  That is, you can't derive EG as a candidate key from the four FDs you've explicitly listed.

Comment: Is EG the only candidate key in this case ?

Comment: No, there's at least one more besides EG.